# How to zip Excel file before it is downloading using Open XML?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel, file

I am using below code to create and it will show user prompt to user whether the user can able to save or open or cancel a excel file.....

I am successfully able to download the file but I need to zip before it is showing user prompt, Later zip file will be showed to the user like with options open or save or cancel.....

How can I do that with not using any other third party library and using Microsoft own **Gzip** DLL?

The below code is for exporting to excel functionality:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{

    byte[] file;
    string targetFilename = string.Format("{0}-{1}.xlsx", "Generated", "excel");

    DataTable dt = common.CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(GetSearchDraftPRResults());
    common.CreateExcelFile excelFileForExport = new CreateExcelFile();
    file = excelFileForExport.CreateExcelDocumentAsStream(dt, targetFilename);
    Response.Buffer = true;
    return File(file, "application/vnd.ms-excel", targetFilename);          
}
```

Would anyone please help on this how to zip a file before it is showing to user?

Many thanks in advance.....

**Modified Code:**

```
    public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {

        byte[] file;
        string targetFilename = string.Format("{0}-{1}.xlsx", "Generated", "excel");

        DataTable dt = common.CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(GetSearchDraftPRResults());
        common.CreateExcelFile excelFileForExport = new CreateExcelFile();
        file = excelFileForExport.CreateExcelDocumentAsStream(dt, targetFilename);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        byte[] zipFile = Compress(file);
        return File(file, "application/vnd.ms-excel", targetFilename);          
    }


    public byte[] Compress(FileInfo fileToCompress)
    {
        using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
        {
            if ((System.IO.File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden & fileToCompress.Extension != ".gz")
            {
                using (FileStream compressedFileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
                {
                    using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);

                    }

                }

            }

            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            CopyStream(originalFileStream, mem);
            return mem.ToArray();
        }

    }


    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[32768];
        int r;
        while ((r = input.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
            output.Write(b, 0, r);
    }
```

Comment: *Microsofts own Gzip.dll*? Which one, do you mean the built-in [compression classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.compression)?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes you are right ....

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SharpZipLib library](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/). It works very well and is free to use even in commercial applications.

Comment: OP asked for the built-in Microsoft library, not any other one.

Comment: GZIP is not a library to create ZIP files. it is GZIP file. This can cause trouble, especially if somebody uses winzip or builtin windows tools. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip
SharpZip is the better choice because it can create zip files.
As a side note: DOes zipping excel files has any benefit? xlsx is a zip after all.

Comment: @ChristianSauer not exactly but this is client requirement .. so I have to zip the excel files....

Comment: @ChristianSauer: That is a good point, but just recommending another library then asked needs some more explanation. Yours explains well why OP should use it.

Comment: @pratapk Then use a library like SharZip, better than a broken implementation

Comment: hmm okk .... but after zipping file I need to show user prompt to save or open or cancel with these options.. how can I show to the user

Comment: @PatrickHofman  would you please check my modified code .. my aim is before showing to user prompt I need to zip it and zip file need to be showed as a user prompt with options ....I am not sure how can I do that using sharp zip .. create zip file on the fly

Comment: @ChristianSauer would you please check my modified code .. my aim is before showing to user prompt I need to zip it and zip file need to be showed as a user prompt with options.. I am not sure how can I do that using sharp zip .. create zip file on the fly

Comment: As stated before, GZIP != ZIP.

Comment: @pratapk Sorry, I don't have expierience with gzip in Asp.net, i have it used in a wpf application.

Comment: @ChristianSauer I am using sharpZip library but I am failing at open the prompt to user...

Answer (score -1):

You can use JZlib from JCraft. Very easy to use, compression declaration can look like this, the code inside depends on what's you doing but you can find working example in JZlib examples:

```
public byte[] compress(byte[] buf, int start, int[] len) {
...
}
```

Comment: OP asked for the built-in Microsoft library, not any other one.